# Creating related attributes when creating new instance of class MVC 4 - Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am just getting into MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5 and want to know if what I am doing is correct?

I have a UserObject and a JobObject, the jobObject has a reference to a User Object.

```
public class Job
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual MyUser User { get; set; }
    public JobType JobType { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to create an instance of the Job I am passing in the query string a parameter UserID, but the Job only deals with an instance of MyUser.

Is the following the correct way to associate the user to the job?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Job job, int userid)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {    
     MyUser staffmember = db.MyUsers.Find(userid);
     if (staffmember == null)
      {
        return View("StaffMemberNotFound");
      }
     job.User = staffmember;
     db.Jobs.Add(job);
     db.SaveChanges(); 
   }
}
```

Or is there a better way to associate the user to the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way will work but I prefer to simply work with ids if possible.

What I would suggest is that you add a `MyUserId` property to your `Job` class (remember to update the database if you are using codefirst):

```
public class Job
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int MyUserId { get; set: }

    public virtual MyUser User { get; set; }
    public JobType JobType { get; set; }
}
```

Then simply populate the `MyUserId`.  You can also change your check to simply check if the id exists as apposed to finding an object and letting EF map that to a class before returning it to you

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Job job, int userid)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {    
     if (!db.MyUsers.Any(u => u.Id == userid)
     {
        return View("StaffMemberNotFound");
     }

     job.MyUserId = userid;
     db.Jobs.Add(job);
     db.SaveChanges(); 
   }
}
```

EF will do the rest of the mapping for you when you next retrieve the record from the database.

Comment: I tried what you suggested (I also deleted the DB so as to start out with a clean DB) but I have one of two issues.

If I add MyUserId then I end up in the DB with two different IDs ie two fields.

MyUserID and MyUser_ID (Entity framework generated id for the user) and my redundant MyUserId

If I create a field called MyUser_ID I get an error about creating two fields with the same name?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My apologies, I thought ef convention would have picked this up.  On your `MyUserId` property add `[ForeignKey("MyUser")]`.  I'll update my answer

Comment: UPDATE: Use `[ForeignKey("User")]` above, not `[ForeignKey("MyUser")]` as previously stated.  My answer is now up to date

Answer (score 0):

**Your approach works fine**, the only small optmization you could make is not taking the "retrieval hit" of `MyUser staffmember = db.MyUsers.Find(userid);` since you already have the `userid`.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5.0, and here is my code (different model objects, but same intent as what you are doing).

Note: I let EF generate my model classes by right-clicking on the `Models` folder and choosing `Add->ADO.NET Entity Data Model` in VS.NET 2012.

**Store.Models.Product**

```
namespace Store.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Store.Models.Category**

```
namespace Store.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On my `Create.cshtml` page, I have the User select the CategoryId from the drop-down list.  This Category Id is bound to `Product.CategoryId`.  All I do in my method is this:

**ProductController**

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    ...
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        product.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        if (dbContext != null)
        {
            dbContext.Products.Add(product);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ...
}
```